# can a form have multiple targets?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, iframe

I have a form that is connected to an iframe, i would like when i submit the form it hits multiple iframes.

```
<form action="{{route('chart.home')}}" method="get" id="" target="Charts">
                        <div>
                            <label for="daterange">Date Range:</label>
                            <input type="date" name="StartDate" id="StartDate"  class="form-control col-md-3"
                                   value="{{isset($searchParams['StartDate']) ? $searchParams['StartDate'] : Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDay(7)->format('yy-m-d')}}"> to
                            <input type="date" name="EndDate" id="EndDate"  class="form-control col-md-3"
                                   value="{{isset($searchParams['EndDate']) ? $searchParams['EndDate'] : Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('yy-m-d')}}">
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-sm btn-white">filter</button>
```

and this iframe

```
 <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" name="Charts" id="iframe" src="{{route('chart.home')}}"></iframe>
```

I want to be able to, on submitting the form, target more iframes like

```
 <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" name="Charts1" id="iframe" src="{{route('chart1.home')}}"  allowfullscreen></iframe>

 <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" name="Charts2" id="iframe" src="{{route('chart2.home')}}"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe using some ajax

Comment: No, that is not directly possible. Maybe you can do this via JavaScript, submit the form to one iframe, then change the form target, and submit it again … But what is the actual _purpose_ of this, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: The code for both of those iframes you have shown appears to be exactly the same, btw., which makes rather little sense to begin with. IDs must be unique within an HTML document, and if you want to be able to target them separately, then their name would have to differ as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms can only have a single target.

Instead, you can use JavaScript to catch the `submit` event on your form and programmatically set the `src` attributes of all `iframe`s.

You can do that using the vanilla [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) or for example using jQuery's [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

**UPDATE (jQuery example):**

```js
$("form[target=Charts]").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var baseSrc = $(this).attr('action');
    var queryArgs = $(this).serialize();
    $('iframe[name=Charts]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('src', baseSrc + '?' + queryArgs);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

another way that works is this function.
the Button() is for a button with an onclick="" in it. hitting the 'form' in document.Form has to match the forms name:

```
    function Button()
{
    document.Form.action = "target action"    // First target
    document.Form.target = "name of target";    // Open in a iframe
    document.Form.submit();        // Submit the page
    document.Form.action = "target action"    // Second target
    document.Form.target = "name of target";    // Open in a iframe
    document.Form.submit();        // Submit the page
    return true;
}
```

you can repeat this as many times as you need to hit all the targets. works very well.